# TCP stream being read by Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I would like to create a Java server socket application that receives a TCP packet and reads the content of it. Based on the contents of the packet it will perform several actions. I managed to get to the point where it reads some content and prints a string System.out.println(sb.toString());
But (a) not all the content is printed and (b) I am not sure how to process the content as they arrive in network order. An example would be to receive an HTTP packet and from the header to report the "Content-Length" or the "User-Agent". Any example would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[ ] args){

PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
int bufferSize = 0;


try{
    String message = args[0];
    int count = 0;

    ServerSocket connectionSocket = null;
    try {
        connectionSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        System.out.println("Server started");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        while(true){
            count++;
            clientSocket = connectionSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("TCP packet received… " +  count);
            InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;


            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());


            clientSocket.close();
        }           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Java alone cannot give you a packet-level interface. You don't 'recieve TCP packets' in java, you just get a data stream. You need to install JPCap, java bindings for the standard packet-capture library.

Comment: I have a script that generates the packet and sends it to the server side (right now both in 'localhost'). I captured it through Wireshark to make sure that the request is correct. So once the script sends the packet to the TCP port 4444 the server reads in the data stream. Do I still need JPcap?

Comment: I suspect the OP just wants to be able to process the stream as it arrives.

Comment: `not all the content is printed ` can you give a simpler example which demonstrates this?

Comment: `how to process the content as they arrive in network order` you are doing this already in your `while` You need to add more code there if you want it to do more.

Comment: When I look the content in the Wireshark the packet shows fine. When I print the content with the above application part of it is printed and several "????" are followed.

Comment: So my questions is mostly, how do I process each specific header field. For instance if for the HTTP header, how do I print out the "Host", the "URI", the "User-Agent", the "Content-Length" etc.

Comment: You're already printing out everything that gets sent. If it doesn't get printed out, it wasn't sent.

Comment: I guess I am getting close it. It is correct, I print everything properly in "strings" (Wireshark prints the same). How can I find out lets say the "Content-Length"? Like search the header and print out a value (if it exists). Shouldn't this be in network order?

Comment: I don't understand the question. 'Network order' refers to byte orderding within binary data. You are receiving HTTP headers, which are character strings, not binary. You have all the headers going past you: if you want the Content-Length header, just do some string comparisons.

Comment: This question isn't about sniffing, it's simply listening on a port. I'm sure there must be umpteen other questions relating to that already on SO. When it comes to reading the headers you'll have to just read the lines as they come in and compare them to the header format you expect.

Comment: @EJP I guess I am not stating properly and thank you for answering. Not all fields are represented as strings in the output. As I said there are some crazy characters (?,>,.). The User-Agent would print fine, but neither Wireshark nor my application prints all bytes in strings. So I want to take them in network order, and proccess the structured header field by field.

Comment: @Thor84no I did not find any other post on Java sockets with "actual" packets. Please advise me if there is one.

Comment: I am using HTTP only as an example. For instance, it may be a DHCP Request (though UDP) that has another formatted header. If I print the MAC address it will not print the correct one since it arrives in network order.

Comment: If it isn't all character data, you shouldn't be using a Reader, you should be using an InputStream. You won't be receiving any DHCP requests or UDP datagrams via your ServerSocket. To reiterate what you've already been told above, you are using a ServerSocket, which commits you to TCP, and therefore to a byte-stream view of the incoming data. There are no packets in this scenario, no sniffing, and no DHCP either. And I still don't understand what you mean by 'network order'. You are getting the bytes in the order they were sent.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I am committed to TCP and that is what I want. Regarding the network order probably it is me not expression correctly. (example) The TCP packets that are received contain a header which is as follows 4Bytes, 4Bytes, 8Bytes (char which is properly printed) and then a payload. How do I print the contents of these in Java?

Comment: You need to read those 4-byte integers with DataInputStream.readInt().

Comment: @JohnPappas You're not dealing with the package level. Also I don't see anything that requires you to. Why would you be interested in package level information as long as the data gets to you in one piece? The whole POINT of using TCP is that you won't have to deal with network details. You certainly don't need packet level information to read HTTP headers such as those you've been talking about up till now, they are part of what you'll be reading from an the InputStream on a socket. If you're reading out parts of this latest header you're talking about in your code it ISN'T a TCP header.

Comment: How are you creating these messages you're trying to read?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "universal protocol decoder". You'll have to implement enough of *each* protocol you intend to decode to get the information you need. If you want to make sense of DHCP packets, you'll need to implement some of the DHCP protocol. It sounds like you're trying to reinvent [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Comment: I think I got it. I have to break BufferedReader in pieces. Then I can process anything that I like. Now I have to find how can I break the BufferedReader in pieces, since read() reads char by char and readline() reads the whole line.

Comment: @JohnPappas, I think you don't got it.